# Why is scrollViewWillEndDragging affecting a UICollectionView and UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm using an UITableView and a UICollectionView on the same View Controller.

I wanted to change how the UICollectionView scrolls, so I added a `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and a `scrollViewWillEndDragging` function inside the extension.

However, `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and a `scrollViewWillEndDragging` is **also** affecting the UITableView, despite not being in the same extension.

How do I fix this? Is there a way to only select the UICollectionView?

Here is a short version of what my code looks like:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // This is where I put all of the UICollectionView code, including `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and a `scrollViewWillEndDragging`

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Why is the code in here affecting the UITableView?

    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        // Same as with `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`

    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // This is where I put all of the UITableView code, it's separate from the UICollectionView so why are `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging` affecting it?

}
```

Comment: You can check superview of scrollView inside the delegate functions. For example: `if let view = scrollview.superView, view == collectionView {}` something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because

> UITableViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDelegate both Inherits From 
>   `UIScrollViewDelegate`

So what you can do is

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // This is where I put all of the UICollectionView code, including `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and a `scrollViewWillEndDragging`

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView is UICollectionView {
          // Add code here for collectionView
        }
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if scrollView is UICollectionView {
          // Add code here for collectionView
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't know UITableViewDelegate also inherited from UIScrollViewDelegate. Now it makes total sense. Thanks!